# Where on disk is the config file of pm2-logrotate module?

Tags: configuration, process-management

Simple question. I'm trying to find the config file of pm2's logrotate module to edit it manually. Unfortunately this information is not provided in the Github repo's README. So where is this file?

Backstory: I accidentally added a config with the incorrect key using `pm2 set pm2-logrotate:wrong-key`. I don't want it to confuse me when I come back to it later. Since there's no way to remove the config line in console (that I am aware of), I would like to get rid of it manually.

Comment: Try `grep -r pm2 /etc/logrotate.*`. And as you seem inexperienced with system administration, be careful when you edit config files in `/etc` manually. Make backups before you change anything.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and console outputs nothing. I think you may have confused Linux's built in logrotate with pm2's logrotate module. In fact I think they are not related at all.

Comment: In this case this may not exactly be a Unix related question, and you may be better off asking over at SO...

Comment: It certainly **does not** belong in SO. Usage and configuration of commercial programs is not within the scope of SO. I did think twice before posting here since pm2 is not a default Linux package, but still it's somewhat popular, and it's **only** available for Linux. So I do believe asking here was a correct choice on my part.

Comment: That's a valid POV.

Comment: Correction: pm2 actually works on Windows too, just not as well as it does on Linux. I don't want my past ignorance to misguide anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

`~/.pm2/module_conf.json`

I believe this file stores configuration for all modules.